# i18n-js in react native: language not loaded on startup

Tags: react-native, internationalization

I have a react native app (ios) with multiple languages. I'm currently facing a weird issue: when I open the app, for a split second, I don't see the translations but I see an error: 'missing translation ...'. This error normally shows up when the translation key is not found (key-value pair) in the json file. Like I said, this error is only there for a split second, after like 500ms, the translations pop up. It seems like the translation file is not loaded properly when the app starts up.

This error is new since the last few days, before that it didn't happen. It also does not happen on the ios simulator, but only when I'm testing on a device. Both the debug scheme and the release scheme have this issue.

My language file looks like this:

```
// en.json
// { key: value }
{
  "hello": "Hello",
  "world": "World",
  ...
}
```

This is my code in react-native:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { _setLanguage } from '../redux/Actions';
import _ from 'lodash';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import * as RNLocalize from "react-native-localize";

const translationGetters = {
  'en': () => require('./translations/en.json')
};

export default useLanguage = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // get the stored language in the redux store (if set)
  const _language = useSelector(state => state.data.config.language);

  // translate function to memoize the language file
  const translate = _.memoize(
    (key, config) => i18n.t(key, config),
    (key, config) => (config ? key + JSON.stringify(config) : key)
  );

  // useEffect function loaded on start up to get the language from redux
  // (if set) or from the device
  // setLanguage() is called to load the correct language file
  useEffect(() => {
    if (_.isNull(_language)) {
      const fallback = { languageTag: 'en' };
      const { languageTag } = RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translationGetters)) || fallback;
      dispatch(_setLanguage({ language: languageTag }));
      setLanguage(languageTag);
    } else {
      setLanguage(_language);
    }
  }, []);

  // setLanguage()
  // sets the language file
  const setLanguage = (language) => {
    translate.cache.clear();
    i18n.translations = { ['en']: translationGetters['en'](), [language]: translationGetters[language]() };
    i18n.locale = language;
    i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
    i18n.fallbacks = true;
    i18n.missingTranslation = () => (null);
    dispatch(_setLanguage({ language }));
  };

  return {
    setLanguage,
    language: _language,
    translate
  };
};
```